# CakePHP: reaching related tables from $Auth->user()

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP 3.7.7. Here my user table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 user_level_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 UNIQUE KEY email (email),
 KEY user_level_id (user_level_id),
 CONSTRAINT users_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (user_level_id) REFERENCES user_levels (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and user_levels:

```
CREATE TABLE user_levels (
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 level varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

in my views I can access to the `level` value, by the foreign key, in this way:

```
<td><?= $user->has('user_level') ? $this->Html->link($user->user_level->level, ['controller' => 'UserLevels', 'action' => 'view', $user->user_level->id]) : '' ?></td>
```

I need to do the same (in `sidebar-menu.ctp, that as no controller associated) with the current logged user retrieved by`$Auth->user()`.
In this case I don't understand what is the correct syntax:

```
$Auth->user()['user_level']
```

leads to:

> Undefined index: user_level

but:

```
$Auth->user()['user_level_id']
```

works, even it's not what I'm looking for.

### UPDATE

Here how I defined `$Auth` in AppController.php:

public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

```
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash', ['clear' => true]);
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
    ]);
}

public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setTheme('AdminLTE');
    $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('AdminLTE.AdminLTE');
    $this->set('Auth', $this->Auth);
}

public function isAuthorized($user = null)
{
    return false;
}
```

and in UsersController.php:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Auth->allow(['login']);
}

public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect.'));
    }
}
```

Comment: To fetch associative data you have to use contain, did you use it ?
see doc https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#namespace-Cake\ORM

Comment: Yes, I put the `contain` instruction in my `index` and `get` functions of `UsersController.php`

Comment: Why not using the methods as they are intended to be used? user() is a notice free convenience wrapper, as such `->user('user_level')` would be usually the right thing to do.

Comment: @mark `$Auth->user('user_level')` in sidebar-menu.ctp is null. Instead in the controller's view contains the actual value.

Comment: Not sure what your Auth object is. I use [AuthUser](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth/blob/master/src/View/Helper/AuthUserHelper.php) helper, which works.

Comment: @mark, question updated.

Comment: Don't pass this controller scoped object along IMO, especially not into the view layer. That's why I have this different solution - which is valid for the view layer.

Comment: @mark, would you mind to provide an answer then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auth component by default only fetch data from single model, in this case users.

If you want to store data in Auth session from relationships then use custom finder in your UsersTable.

**Example Auth settings:**

```
'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'finder' => 'emailOrNameAuth',
                    'fields' => ['username' => 'name', 'password' => 'password']
                ]
            ],
```

**UsersTable:**

```
public function findEmailOrNameAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->where(
            [
                'OR' => [
                'email' => $options['username'],
                'name' => $options['username']
                ],
                'activated' => 1,
            ]
        )
        ->contain(['UserLevels']); // <---- 

    return $query;
}
```

**Read:**

https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Auth.FormAuthenticate.html

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-find-methods

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query